# Serving a static page using nginx - getting 404

Tags: nginx, django

I'm trying to set up a static page on my website using nginx. The folder has a `index.html` file along with some static files.

The directory structure looks something like this

```
olx
--static
--fonts
--index.html
```

This is how I'm trying to serve the `index.html` page.

```
location /olx {
    root /mypath/olx;

    default_type "text/html";
    try_files  $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html index.html;
}
```

This gives me a 404 error. Any help?

Comment: What's the request you are sending ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
location /olx {
root /mypath/olx;
```

Change it to:

```
location /olx {
root /mypath;
```